# Outbound emails disappearing/not displaying in Mandrill

Tags: mandrill

I did an export of outbound emails and its only showing me emails starting at the 5th of the month, instead of from the 1st. I know there were emails sent on the 1st, as I have a report of these.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing this behavior. It is because Mandrill only holds 1 month history of detailed information. so lets say, you ran the export on Sep 5th, you get only 30 day old data from the point of execution of the API (from aug 5th ).

From Mandrill website link https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583157-How-long-does-Mandrill-keep-data-about-my-emails-

Detailed information for delivered messages is stored for 30 days, while bounced message data is kept for 90 days for record-keeping purposes.

Hope this helps,